# php currency slows page

Tags: php, currency

I have a page whit ads, and i set the page currency in "RON" and i convert to show also in "Euro" but in the loop is very slow..  I tried to include the script form other php but stil the same... I tried many currency changer but all have the same problem.. slow the page down.. and if i put the code directly in to the loop  then tells me an error: that the class could not be repeated.
here is the php currency what i used:

```
<?php 
class cursBnrXML
 {

     var $currency = array();

    function cursBnrXML($url)
    {
        $this->xmlDocument = file_get_contents($url);
        $this->parseXMLDocument();
    }


    function parseXMLDocument()
    {
         $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($this->xmlDocument);

         $this->date=$xml->Header->PublishingDate;

         foreach($xml->Body->Cube->Rate as $line)    
         {                      
             $this->currency[]=array("name"=>$line["currency"], "value"=>$line, "multiplier"=>$line["multiplier"]);
         }
    }
    function getCurs($currency)
    {
        foreach($this->currency as $line)
        {
            if($line["name"]==$currency)
            {
                return $line["value"];
            }
        }

        return "Incorrect currency!";
    }
 }
//@an example of using the cursBnrXML class
$curs=new cursBnrXML("http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml");
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `cursBnrXML` class to **cache** parsed currency so that you do not have to loop over entire collection again each look up.

```
<?php 
class cursBnrXML
 {

    private $_currency = array();

    # keep the constructor the same


    # modify this method
    function parseXMLDocument()
    {
         $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($this->xmlDocument);

         $this->date=$xml->Header->PublishingDate;

         foreach($xml->Body->Cube->Rate as $line)    
         {                      
             $this->currency[$line["currency"]]=array(
                "value"=>$line, 
                "multiplier"=>$line["multiplier"]
             );
         }
    }

    # modify this method too
    function getCurs($currency)
    {
        if (isset($this->_currency[$currency])) 
        {
             return $this->_currency[$currency]['value'];
        }

        return "Incorrect currency!";
    }
 }
//@an example of using the cursBnrXML class
$curs=new cursBnrXML("http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml");
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but new in php in beginner status .. 
maybe you can help me with some code ...

Comment: The above code is the modified version of your `cursBnrXML` class.

Comment: Somewhere in the end is an error(Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{') in the end of the script somewhere here:   `    function getCurs($currency)
    {
        if (isset($this->_currency[$currency]) {
             return $this->_currency[$currency]['value'];
        }

        return "Incorrect currency!";
    }`